# Stationary distributions of diffusion $dX(t) = -\nabla U(X(t))dt + \sqrt{2}dB_t^d$, when $U$ is $C^1(R^d \to R)$ and $\nabla U$ is Lipschitz

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-differential-equations

Let $U:\mathbb R^d \to \mathbb R$ be a continuously differentiable function such that $Z_U:= \int_{\mathbb R^d}e^{-U(x)}dx < \infty$ and consider the Gibbs distribution $\pi(dx) := Z_U^{-1}e^{-U(x)}dx$. Consider the diffusion equation generated by the gradient of $U$, namely
$$
dX(t) = -\nabla U(X(t))dt + \sqrt{2}dB_t^d,
$$

where $B_t^d$ is Brownian motion on $\mathbb R^d$. It can be shown that if

> **A1.** $U$ is strongly-convex,
> **A2.** $U$ is $L$-smooth, that is $\|\nabla U(x)-\nabla U(y)\| \le L\|x-y\|$ for all $x,y \in \mathbb R^d$,

then $\pi$ is the unique unique stationary distribution of the above diffusion, i.e the unique invariant distribution of the Markov semigroup $(P_t)_{t \in \mathbb R}$ which acts on bounded measurable functions $f: \mathbb R^d \to \mathbb R$ by $P_tf := \mathbb E[f(X(t)) \mid X(0) = x]$.

> **Question.** *What can be said if the strong-convexity assumption **A1** is removed ?*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convexity of $U$ is irrelevant for convergence to the stationary measure. All that is needed is coercivity: you need to make sure $|U(x)| \rightarrow \infty$ fast enough as $|x| \rightarrow \infty$.

You have a Markov process that is irreducible in a suitable sense, and you can guess the invariant measure by checking that the density $p(x) = C\exp(-U(x))$ satisfies the invariance equation,
$$\mathcal{L}^* p = \frac{\partial}{\partial x}\left(\frac{\partial U}{\partial x}p(x)\right) + \frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2} p(x) = 0,$$
where $\mathcal{L}^*$ is the adjoint of the infinitesimal generator of your process. By standard Markov process theory, the process $X_t$ converges in distribution to your $\pi(dx)$.

For a proof in precisely this setup, see Theorem 2.1 of [http://www2.stat.duke.edu/~scs/Courses/Stat376/Papers/ConvergeRates/GeneralState/RobertsTweedie1996.pdf](http://www2.stat.duke.edu/%7Escs/Courses/Stat376/Papers/ConvergeRates/GeneralState/RobertsTweedie1996.pdf) .